# What type of attack should be used in order to pass this authentication

Tags: passwords, authentication, attacks

I am practicing the [Astalavista Wargames](http://www.astalavista.com/index.php?app=hackingchallenge&module=gamemod&section=challenge&challid=263) and i came across this challenge. The question is:
Bob wrote a piece of software but the password verification doesn't seem to work. You must find a way to
log on. We were able to recover some part of the source:

```
typedef struct {char pass[5],valid;} password;

int main(){
    password s;
    s.valid=0;
    scanf("%s",s.pass);
    verifypass(s);
    //if password is correct the value of s.valid will change to 1
    if(s.valid==1)login();
    else printf("Wrong passwordn");
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[Link to original provided executable file in the question](http://www.astalavista.com/hackingchallenge_levels/raven_exploit01.rar) . Note that the question does not provide anything else beside this part of code and executable file.

My initial thought was that this should be done using buffer overflow attacks, so just as a common approach on my x64 machine I try to enter 1 to change the valid bit to TRUE.

when I enter this number of 1's "1111111111111111111111111111" the program allows me to enter the password again, BUT not logging in. If I enter less, it would show the wrong password and exit and if I enter more it would crash.

How can I come up with a solution to this challenge?

Comment: have you tried entering characters with the ASCII code 1 `(char)1`, not with the digit `'1'` (ascii 49)?

Comment: It is worth pointing out that a boolean value of 1 is not the same as a string value of 1, so your approach wouldn't necessarily put the right value in even if it was at the correct spot.

Comment: You have not provided enough code to answer this question.  Where is the `verifypass` function???

Comment: @Rook This is as provided in the question. The challenge is that you have only this part of code available. How can you get to pass login.

Comment: @CodesInChaos it has the same effect as 1's. you can try for yourself too and tell me if i'm wrong

Comment: @AJHenderson I hear you, but then it would work out if I write the ascii code. Which it doesn't.

Comment: @Erfan - yeah, I didn't expect it would be that simple.  You normally need to redirect a particular function return with an overflow, otherwise you would also overwrite the function that you want to impact.  I just didn't have time to look in to the actual answer and wanted to make sure to point out the immediately evident problem.

Comment: @Erfan Just looking at the source, writing `49` (`'1'`) into the `valid` byte would fail the `==1` test, but writing `1` would pass.

Comment: @CodesInChaos So you mean trying the 1's at the first place, was right?

Comment: @Erfan in the future you should post the entire challenge.  I still don't see the verifypass() function.  You are not going to get a valid answer without providing all of the information.

Comment: @Rook I told you already, this IS the entire challenge. You can visit the link of challenge to verify my word. There is no more code or information more than this. The link is in the question as _Astalavista Wargames_.

Comment: @Erfan this code will not compile,  how did you get a .exe?

Comment: @Rook Please read the question carefully. I have written **Link to the original executable file provided by question**. This code and exe file both are provided in the question. No more codes or other files. The challenge is to find a way to log in _only_ having this information.

Answer (score 2):

You would be able to attack this with a buffer overflow, but it is not necessary. In order to get a buffer overflow exploit working you will need to perform dynamic analysis on the exe, using a tool such as [OllyDBG](http://www.ollydbg.de/). You would then run the program, passing it overlong strings until you get it to crash. The type of crash you are looking for is control over `eip`. Typically you would just pass a whole string of `AAAAAA` and check the CPU registers when the program crashes, if you see `eip 0x41414141` or similar, you win and are just a few steps away from breaking the code.

However, I would attack this in a very different way. The password is stored in the `exe` file, but it is obfusticated - it is generated by multiplying and rotating a series of values such as `0x55555556` and `0x66666667`. It then compares your password against the generated value, and branches one way or another depending on whether they match. All you need to do is subvert this branching condition. This can be achieved very easily with a hex-editor.

For a clue; the command you want to edit resides at `0x4013b3 (_main+58)`.

Comment: It is not possible to control the EIP in this code.  The Main is a special function that doesn't return.

Comment: @Rook you could be right, I only gave it a very quick glance over in IDA, saw a small buffer, a string copy command, and a function call (verifypass) and just assumed.